# SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Issue - BIDS quits unexpectedly when attempting to preview a report

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, bids

I've run into a problem using BIDS in Visual Studio 2008.

Whilst working through the MSDN tutorial on [Reporting Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337396.aspx) BIDS will quit unexpectedly when attempting to Preview a chart. There are no error messages - it just quits.

The Event Viewer gives the following information:

> Date: 09/09/11
>
> Source: .NET Runtine
>
> Time: 12:49:10
>
> Category: None
>
> Type: Error
>
> Event ID: 1023
>
> User: N/A
>
> .NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.3623 - Fatal Execution Engine Error
>   (7A05ADE0) (80131506)
>
> For more information, see Help and Support Center at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

Digging around online, there are a few suggestions that RedGate Prompt 5 is to blame, but I don't have that installed. I also tried to re-install .NET 3.5 SP1 but the problem persists.

I've installed the AdventureWorks databases onto SQL Server 2008 R2 Express with Advanced Services. In the RDL file in question, the datasets all return data from their queries.

I've actually found a way to stop BIDS crashing, and that is by editing each of the report parameters and changing their available and default values to None. Then when I click Preview I get to the screen asking me for the input parameters (which I can't enter in some instances if I get the available values from a query, for example).

This issue is a bit of a showstopper for me but is very simple to reproduce given the simple nature of the MSDN tutorial.

Can anyone help?

Thanks,

Iain McKinley

Comment: Did you try uninstalling and reinstalling .NET 2.0?

Comment: I tried that. I can un-install .NET 2.0 but can't re-install it. I get an error message saying "error 25007: error occurred while initializing fusion".

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve? I'm experiencing the same issue.